# Impossible to get my pager

Tags: forms, paging

I need to show in the same page a form and a table which shows all results from a webservice response.

```
function collectivite_search_user_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
      '#required'   => True,
    );
    $form['firstname'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Firstname'),
      //'#required'   => True,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    if (isset($form_state['table'])) {
        $form['table'] = $form_state['table'];
    }
    return $form;
}


function collectivite_search_user_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'collectivite', 'collectivite.api');
    $results = collectivite_ws_get_users($form_state['values']['name'], $form_state['values']['firstname']);
    if(is_object($results->Dossier)){
            $rows[] = array(
                'id'       => $results->Dossier->id,
                'nom'       => $results->Dossier->nom,
                'prenom'    => $results->Dossier->prenom,
            );
    }else{
        foreach($results->Dossier as $dossier) {        
            $rows[] = array(
                'id'       => $dossier->id,
                'nom'       => $dossier->nom,
                'prenom'    => $dossier->prenom,
            );
        }

    }


    $paging = pager_array_splice($rows, 5);
    $header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));

    $form_state['table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $paging,
      '#empty' => t('Aucun résultat.')
    );
    $form_state['rebuild'] = True;
}

function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

  // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
  $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);

  // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
  $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
  $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
  $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
  return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
```

It works fine except I cannot see the pagination. Can you see where is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {
      global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
      $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

      // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
      $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);

      // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
      $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
      $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
      $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
      return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
    }

    $output = pager_array_splice($yourarray, 5);
```

$output = '';
  $your_array = some_method_to_get_array();
  $tree = pager_array_splice($your_array, 5);
  // Do something with the 5 terms
  $output .= theme('pager', array('quantity' => 5));

Comment: I don't understand, I already have this code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a call to `theme('pager')` for your output.  Also, to maybe simplify things, you could use `pager_default_initialize`.  Below is an example from the [Drupal.org API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7).

```
// Now that we have the total number of results, initialize the pager.
pager_default_initialize($result->total, $num_per_page);

// Display the search results.
$output = theme('search_results', array('results' => $result->data, 'type' => 'remote'));

// Finally, display the pager controls, and return.
$output .= theme('pager');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do not understand how to return an output because my form is already returning a form object.

Comment: I always found working with pagers a little bit of a mind bend.  The pager is not actually part of the form, but a separate themed element in the page that appends params to the current url when navigating, the developer being responsible for parsing and using the arguments. If you have access to the `page_callback` it is best to place the `theme('pager')` there as part of the rendered page content, else you can append it to the form elements as a markup type.